# Why choose a JSON array over a JSON object or vice versa

Tags: arrays, json, object

I would like to know what advantages there are (if any) with choosing a JSON array over a JSON object? Do you have an example where it's clear that one choice is better than another?

I have the following example:

JSON Array:

```
[ {"animal" : "deer", "colour" : "brown"}, {"animal" : "sloth", "colour" : "gray"}]
```

JSON Object:

```
 {"animalList" : [
      {"animal" : "deer", "colour" : "brown"}, 
      {"animal" : "sloth", "colour" : "gray"}  
    ]}
```

but can't really see any advantage in choosing one over the other. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In this example, there is not advantage. But if you need obvious grouping, for example if you often need to group animals by their class, there is an advantage in writing this:

```
{
    "birds": [
        {"animal" : "eagle", "colour" : "brown"}, 
        {"animal" : "pigeon", "colour" : "gray"}
    ],
    "mammals" :[
        {"animal" : "lion", "colour" : "yellow"}, 
        {"animal" : "tiger", "colour" : "orange"}  
    ]
}
```

over this:

```
{"animal" : "eagle", "colour" : "brown"}, 
{"animal" : "pigeon", "colour" : "gray"}
{"animal" : "lion", "colour" : "yellow"}, 
{"animal" : "tiger", "colour" : "orange"}
```

because you remove the need for filtering them by just accessing them by key like `animals['birds']`.

Objects provide a fast access by *key* over fast access by *position*. You chose to write an animal like this:

```
{"animal" : "deer", "colour" : "brown"}
```

but you could also have written:

```
[
    {
        "key": "animal",
        "value": "eagle"
    },
    {
        "key": "colour",
        "value": "brown"
    }
]
```

If you didn't, it is because you already understand the advantage of accessing the animal colour with `animal['colour']`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean wrapping an array in an object in an AJAX response?

In older browsers, returning an array can lead to **security vulnerabilities**, as [detailed in this blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx/).  I believe mainstream browsers are no longer vulnerable to it, but cannot find the source.  However, security is belt-and-braces, so always return an object as an AJAX response *anyway*.

Comment: Yeah, I guess the second code example is wrapping an array in an object. Just wondering if there's any reason to choose one or the other as both seem to work and are effectively the same!

Answer (score 0):

Arrays have functions defined which cannot be run directly on objects. Like `sort`, `map` and so on